# Salesforce return value from function based on input

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-variable

I am a complete novice in Salesforce, learning as I go, but I want to make sure I structure something in the best way as it can be a bit of a beast to manage if I don't.

I am building some VisualForce pages that have links in them based on a field, but the domains are generic across all these fields so I would ideally like to have a generic function that I can call.

For example, I have the field CountryID__c, based on this, I understand that I can generate my URL based on a formula.

```
<apex:page standardController="CountryRef__c">
    <!-- use a variable?
      String domain = 'https://';
    -->
    <!-- ClientPK: {!CountryRef__c.ClientID__c} -->
    <apex:iframe src="https://www.companyxyz{!IF((CountryRef__c.CountryID__c==""49""),"".de"",IF((CountryRef__c.CountryID__c=='44'),'.co.uk',IF((CountryRef__c.CountryID__c=='61'),'.com.au','.com')))}}/?id={!CountryRef__c.ClientID__c}" scrolling="true" id="CountryReferenceEmbedded"/>
</apex:page>
```

But if I have a load of these pages and we were to add in New Zealand (".co.nz"), then there would be loads of these pages where I would need to update this.

What would be the best practice for organising this?

Comment: You have multiple options -- 1) use apex:include ; 2) use apex components so you have only one file to manage

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension to provide a common variable:

```
public class CountryExtension {
  public String countryUrl { get; set; }
  private CountryRef__c country;
  public CountryExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    country = (CountryRef__c)controller.getRecord();
    countryUrl = 'https://www.companyxyz';
    Map<Integer, String> tlds = new Map<Integer, String> {
      49 => '.de',
      44 => '.co.uk',
      61 => '.com.au'
    };
    String tld = tlds.get(country.CountryId__c);
    if(tld == null) {
      tld = '.com';
    }
    countryUrl += tld + '?id='+country.ClientId__c;
  }
}
```

Now, you can include that as an extension and use the variable on any page that uses that standardController:

```
<apex:page standardController="CountryRef__c" extensions="CountryExtension">
    <apex:iframe src="{!countryUrl}" scrolling="true" id="CountryReferenceEmbedded"/>
</apex:page>
```

As a bonus, it cleans up the complicated formula and replaces it with a simple merge field.

Every page that uses this extension gets a free upgrade whenever you modify the extension.

Comment: This is fabulous.  Is it possible to dynamically reference the object (CountryRef__c) as we have Business__c (always named the same) on a couple of other objects?

<code>
private CountryRef__c country;    -->     private {DYNAMIC_OBJECT} r;
country = (r)controller.getRecord();
</code>

Everything else could remain the same?

Comment: @G-Man You can use [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) as a generic record holder, then use a [switch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) to work with various types of records.